L.c.i locus of Hilbert scheme of points on singular varieties
Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$. What can we say about the l.c.i. locus of $\text{Hilb}^n(X)$?
When $X$ is smooth, it is well-known that the l.c.i. locus of $\text{Hilb}^n(X)$ is smooth. However, if we weaken the assumptions on $X$ (for instance, assuming $X$ is l.c.i., normal, orbifold, etc.)—what can be said about the l.c.i. locus of $\text{Hilb}^n(X)$?
In particular, are there assumptions on $X$ that ensure the l.c.i. locus of $\text{Hilb}^n(X)$ is reduced?
Thank you in advance for your insights!

You have the same result for the maximal open subscheme of $\text{Hilb}^n(X)$ over which the universal closed immersion $Z\hookrightarrow \text{Hilb}^n(X)\times X$ is a "regular embedding," i.e., the ideal sheaf is everywhere locally generated by a regular sequence.  However, already for $\text{Hilb}^1(X) = X$, you can see that you cannot do better than that when $X$ is singular.

In the special case that $X$ is a normal surface, there is a little more that we can say.  By the Hilbert-Burch-Schaps theorem, if the projective dimension of the structure sheaf of $Z$ equals $2$ (i.e., if the structure sheaf has finite projective dimension), then $\text{Hilb}^n(X)$ is locally smooth near $[Z]$.
